# User mod_rewrite to fake subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

My current web root directory has:

/product-a.php

/product-b.php

How to I rewrite it so that:

1. it auto detects and displays all URL ending with /product-a.php on my site to become /products/product-a
2. when clicking onto these links /products/product-a it send back requests as /product-a.php

Thanks for your help!

Andy

Comment: Can you try to add some clarity. What do you want to be auto detected?

Comment: Sorry when I mean was all requests to /products/product-a should be sent to internal as /product-a.php. Directory /products is non-existent actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```